# About Theorem 13.6 on p.110 in "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres. An integral over the empty set.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

> Theorem 13.6. Let $S$ be a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded continuous function; let $A=\operatorname{Int}S$. If $f$ is integrable over $S$, then $f$ is integrable over $A$, and $\int_S f=\int_A f$.

Let $S$ be a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Suppose that $S=\operatorname{Bd}S$.
Suppose that $S$ has measure zero.
Let $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary bounded function.
Suppose that $f$ is integrable over $S$.
Then, $\int_S f=0$ (by Theorem 11.3(a) on p.96).
$A=\operatorname{Int}S=\emptyset$.
And the author didn't define an integral over the empty set.
Can we define $\int_\emptyset f := 0$?

Or do we need to modify the above theorem as follows?

> Theorem 13.6*. Let $S$ be a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\operatorname{Int}S\neq\emptyset$; let $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded continuous function; let $A=\operatorname{Int}S$. If $f$ is integrable over $S$, then $f$ is integrable over $A$, and $\int_S f=\int_A f$.

Comment: Actually $\int_Sf=\int1_Sf$ by definition where $1_S$ is the indicator function of set $S$. If $S=\varnothing$ then its indicator is the zero-function and $\int0=0$.

Comment: @drhab Thank you very much for your answer.